# for loop only generate one excel sheet in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a method that I want to run for each instance of an object class. The final result should be an excel sheet for each instance (i.e. person) of the class. But with the current code, I am only getting one. Any ideas?

[image: example]

```
import random
import pandas as pd

people = []

class Utovere:
    def __init__(self, navn, skigymnas):
        self.navn = navn
        self.skigymnas = skigymnas
        people.append(self)

    #def allokeringTilGruppe(self):

    @staticmethod
    def allokeringRandom(printToCSV=False):
        dn = []
        for i in range(3):
            loype = ['STRAIGHT-GLIDING', 'STRAIGHT-GLIDING', 'LØYPE 1', 'LØYPE 1', 'LØYPE 1', 'LØYPE 2', 'LØYPE 2', 'LØYPE 2', 'LØYPE 3', 'LØYPE 3', 'LØYPE 3']
            dn.append(['STRAIGHT-GLIDING'] + random.sample(loype, len(loype)))
        df = pd.DataFrame(dn).transpose()
        df = df.rename(
            columns={0: "Treningsdag 1", 1: "Treningsdag 2", 2: "Treningsdag 3"}
        )
        print(df)
        if printToCSV == True:
            df.to_csv(
                'bra.csv'
            )
        return df

# Creating the instances of the class
Christian = Utovere('Christian', 'HSG')
beate = Utovere('BHJBHUBJBHJ', 'HSG')
Simen= Utovere('Simen', 'HSG')
Bra = Utovere('Bra', 'HSG')


#Function to create the excel files
def funger():
    dataliste = []
    for person in people:
        dataramme = Utovere.allokeringRandom()
        df = pd.DataFrame(dataramme)
        with pd.ExcelWriter('index.xlsx') as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=person.navn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your writer object before your for loop:

```
#Function to create the excel files
def funger():
    with pd.ExcelWriter('index.xlsx') as writer:
        dataliste = []
        for person in people:
            dataramme = Utovere.allokeringRandom()
            df = pd.DataFrame(dataramme)
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=person.navn)
```

Comment: damn 4 seconds faster than me xD

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Solution.

```
def funger():
    dataliste = []
    with pd.ExcelWriter('index.xlsx') as writer:
        for person in people:
            dataramme = Utovere.allokeringRandom()
            df = pd.DataFrame(dataramme)
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=person.navn)
```